# Filter by item name in - Inventory management/Inquiries/On-hand

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

As far as I understand, ProductName column is shown via a display methods. At least for my implementation here and this method resides in InventSum table:

```
display public ItemNameDisplay itemName()
{
    // Fields might not have been selected on the specified buffers, or might have been updated since selection
    this.checkInvalidFieldAccess(false);

    if (this.InventDimId)
    {
        return this.inventTable().itemName(InventDim::find(this.InventDimId));
    }
    return this.inventTable().itemName();
}
```

When I hit Ctrl + G and try to filter the data, this option is disabled for the above column and I think this happens due to that display method.  Is there any way I could achieve this functionality?

Should I try ( at right click ) to add another MenuItem there and do the filtering with the help of a new dialog ( where i will write down the item name),somehow followed by a refresh on the form?

**Update 1:**

I've found and edited this approach for my special case:

```
public void context()
{
   InventTable inventTable;

   int selectedMenu;
   real test;
   formrun fr;
   Args ag;
   Itemname strtext;
   querybuilddataSource qb1;
   queryrun qr;
   query q;
   PopupMenu menu = new PopupMenu(element.hWnd());
   int a = menu.insertItem('Find');
   int c = menu.insertItem('Remove Filter');


   selectedMenu = menu.draw();

   switch (selectedMenu)
   {
       case -1:
       break;

       case a:
       ag = new args('SysformSearch');
       fr = new formrun(ag);
       fr.run();
       fr.wait();
       strtext = fr.design().controlName('FindEdit').valueStr();

      if(strtext)
      {
          select ItemId from inventTable
          where inventTable.NameAlias == strtext;

          InventSum_DS.filter(FieldNum(InventSum,ItemId),Sysquery::value(inventTable.ItemId));
      }
      break;

      case c :
          InventSum_DS.removeFilter();
      break;

      Default:
      break;
   }
}
```

Still I think is not the correct way to just display a new PopupMenu. I would like to hook to the usual menu and add the new Find and Remove Filter right there. And .. remove filter takes a while, I should signal this somehow so the user don't panic.

Comment: Do you want to filter by item name (as stated in your question) or by name alias (as implemented in your update 1)? The possible solutions are quite different for these two fields.

Comment: @FH-Inway, I would like to filter by item name.

Comment: I can't seem to control the things this way. If the user wants to have many results I will have to add many ranges and perform a strScan somehow to check all the values which contain the desired string, and maybe the string contains * or ! etc.. i am going nowhere..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found this article:

[Join ItemName from (EcoResProductTranslation )](http://hellodax.com/2015/06/19/join-itemname-from-ecoresproducttranslation-and-search-name-from-inventtable-to-onhand-form-for-search-matter/)

Basically, we create a query based on InventTable, EcoResProduct and EcoResProductTranslation in order to get the name of the product starting from the Product field in the InventTable.

A new relation is added on InventSum:

[image]

On InventOnHandItem > DataSources > InventSum > Methods > executeQuery I've added the new ds:

```
element.inventDimSetupObject().modifyQuery(inventSum_DS,inventDim_DS, InventLookupView_ds);
```

And in the class :

InventDimCtrl_Frm_OnHand > modifyQuery, I've added this parameter:

```
FormDataSource _inventLookup = null
```

so now i have this:

```
public void modifyQuery(
   FormDataSource _inventSum_DS,
   FormDataSource _inventDim_DS,
   FormDataSource _inventLookup = null
)
```

A query build data source instance :

```
QueryBuildDataSource    qbsInventLookup;
```

And this section of code:

```
if(_inventLookup)
{
    qbsInventLookup = query.dataSourceName(_inventLookup.name());

    //filter current company language
    //qbr = SysQuery::findOrCreateRange(qbsInventLookup, fieldnum(InventLookupView, LanguageId));
    //qbr.value(queryValue(CompanyInfo::languageId()));

    qbsInventLookup.addGroupByField(fieldNum(InventLookupView, Name));
    //qbsInventLookup.addGroupByField(fieldNum(InventLookupView,NameAlias));
}
```

The newly created view is added as a data source in the InventSum :

[image]

And drag the Name field from this data source to the grid. It worked just fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Using a context menu is not the way to do it, complements for the idea though.

What you need to do extend the form with datasources for the required field.
In this case it requires `InventTable` inner joined to `InventSum`, `EcoResProduct` inner joined to `InventTable` and `EcoresProductTranslation` inner joined to `EcoResProduct`. Add the field `EcoresProductTranslation.Name` as a field in the grid.

You will have to do a range on the preferred language. There will be no output if no translation to that language exists.

As the query is a group by query, you will need to group by on `EcoresProductTranslation.Name`.
The code of the form is rather convoluted, so it may be a pain to make it work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response Jan. I've got it working Friday evening.. couldn't start the weekend without this .. i think something is missing on my side.. i commented out the language part in order for it to work.